# Efficient way to plot a set of large data and calculate slopes in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, large-data

I have a text file with 32 columns.

> Ev         col 2, col 3,  col 4,  col 5,   col 6,  col 7  col 8  col 9  col 10    etc...(total 32 columns)
>
> -0.08, 8.300, 8.300, 8.300, 8.301, 8.300, 8.300, 8.300, 8.301, 3.405...(total 32 columns)
>
> -0.04, 8.300, 8.300, 8.300, 8.301, 8.300, 8.300, 8.300, 8.301, 3.405... (total 32 columns)
>
> 0.00, 8.300, 8.300, 8.300, 8.301, 8.300, 8.300, 8.300, 8.301, 3.405... (total 32 columns)
>
> 0.04, 8.300, 8.300, 8.300, 8.301, 8.300, 8.300, 8.300, 8.301, 3.405... (total 32 columns)
>
> 0.08, 8.300, 8.300, 8.300, 8.301, 8.300, 8.300, 8.300, 8.301, 3.405... (total 32 columns)

I would like to plot all the 32 columns on the right versus the left one. (i.e. Ev vs col2, Ev vs col3..... Ev vs col 32) and calculate their slopes.

So I tried the bruteforce method-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9, y10, y11, y12, y13, y14, y15, y16, y17, y18, y19, y20, y21, y22, y23, y24, y25, y26, y27, y28, y29, y30, y31, y32 = np.loadtxt('mydata.txt', delimiter=',', unpack=True)


slope1, intercept1 = np.polyfit(x1, y1, 1)
slope1, intercept1 = np.polyfit(x1, y2, 1)
slope1, intercept1 = np.polyfit(x1, y3, 1)
slope1, intercept1 = np.polyfit(x1, y4, 1)
#..... All the way upto 32nd column
print('slope 1 =',slope1)

plt.plot(x1,y1, label='With ',marker='o')
plt.plot(x1,y2, label='With ',marker='o')
plt.plot(x1,y3, label='With ',marker='o')
plt.plot(x1,y4, label='With ',marker='o')
plt.plot(x1,y5, label='With ',marker='o')
#.
#.
#.
#....All the way upto 32nd columns 
# ...plt.plot(x1,y32, label='mydata ',marker='o')

plt.show()
```

Even though this code works, I know this is not the efficient way. Is there a better way of **plotting** these data and get the **slopes**?

Comment: These plots supposed to be straight lines. Not scattered plots. Also is there a way to calculate slopes on pairplot?

Comment: But 'reg' only plot regression line, not the line connecting points.

Comment: If I may correct the way you describe your achievement: You want to plot all the 32 columns on the right _versus_ the left one. This is what you do manually and call `bruteforce'

Comment: @SpghttCd Yes, I would like to plot all 32 columns on right vs the left one and also calculate slopes.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't explicitly put the result of `np.loadtxt` into 33 different variables. Put it into one, called `data` for example and index it the way you need.

```
data = np.loadtxt('mydata.txt', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
plt.plot(data[0], data[1:])
```

perhaps you have to transpose it before, like

```
data = data.T
```

or use

```
plt.plot(data[:, 0], data[:, 1:])
```

However, I'd recommend to use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), index_col=0)
df.plot()
```

With regards to your slope calculation:

```
data = data.T

array([[-0.08 , -0.04 ,  0.   ,  0.04 ,  0.08 ],
       [ 8.3  ,  8.3  ,  8.3  ,  8.3  ,  8.3  ],
       [ 8.3  ,  8.3  ,  8.3  ,  8.3  ,  8.3  ],
       [ 8.3  ,  8.3  ,  8.3  ,  8.3  ,  8.3  ],
       [ 8.301,  8.301,  8.301,  8.301,  8.301],
       [ 8.3  ,  8.3  ,  8.3  ,  8.3  ,  8.3  ],
       [ 8.3  ,  8.3  ,  8.3  ,  8.3  ,  8.3  ],
       [ 8.3  ,  8.3  ,  8.3  ,  8.3  ,  8.3  ]])

for y in data[1:]:
    print(np.polyfit(data[0], y, 1))

[ -1.12054027e-14   8.30000000e+00]
[ -1.12054027e-14   8.30000000e+00]
[ -1.12054027e-14   8.30000000e+00]
[  7.45493703e-15   8.30100000e+00]
[ -1.12054027e-14   8.30000000e+00]
[ -1.12054027e-14   8.30000000e+00]
[ -1.12054027e-14   8.30000000e+00]
```

or with the `pandas` dataframe:

```
df

        col 2   col 3   col 4   col 5   col 6   col 7  col 8
Ev                                                          
-0.08     8.3     8.3     8.3   8.301     8.3     8.3    8.3
-0.04     8.3     8.3     8.3   8.301     8.3     8.3    8.3
 0.00     8.3     8.3     8.3   8.301     8.3     8.3    8.3
 0.04     8.3     8.3     8.3   8.301     8.3     8.3    8.3
 0.08     8.3     8.3     8.3   8.301     8.3     8.3    8.3

for name, data in df.iteritems():
    print(name, np.polyfit(data.index, data.values, 1))

col 2 [ -1.12054027e-14   8.30000000e+00]
col 3 [ -1.12054027e-14   8.30000000e+00]
col 4 [ -1.12054027e-14   8.30000000e+00]
col 5 [  7.45493703e-15   8.30100000e+00]
col 6 [ -1.12054027e-14   8.30000000e+00]
col 7 [ -1.12054027e-14   8.30000000e+00]
col 8 [ -1.12054027e-14   8.30000000e+00]
```

Comment: nice answer, it's better than pairplot for this problem +1

Comment: Is there a way to get the slopes?

Comment: I'm not really sure what slopes other than `0` you expect by 32 lists of constant values, but anyway - your slope calculation doesn't have anything to do with your plots, so you could apply `polyfit` to your x-y-data as before. I'll update...